# Application is working in iOS4.0 or higher but it's crashing immediately after launch on device 3.1.3 or lower

Tags: iphone, ios4

I've an application which is working fine on iOS 4.0 or higher but keep crashing immediately  after launch on device 3.1.3 or lower. I've set "Base SDK" to "4.1" and "Deployment Target" to "3.0".

Crash Log -

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/FE470A03-6285-48E4-B188-A0023500AA84/XXX
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
  Dyld Version: 149

I've weak linking to new frameworks.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant *UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey* was introduced with iOS 3.2. So it's not available on a 3.1.3 device. Furthermore, the constant is defined in the UIKit framework. So weakly linking to *new* frameworks is not sufficient because UIKit is an *old* framework.

I see two options:

1. Switch to weak linking for UIKit (and make sure the constant isn't used on older devices).
2. Replace the use of *UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey* with *UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey*. It's deprecated and works slightly differently. But it still works.

Comment: I'll try weak linking UIKit.but I am sure I haven't used UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey in my project. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Weak Linking "UIKit" framework did the trick. And one more line that crashing a application was using "UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification" without checking whether it's available or not.
Following checking has fixed that issue.

```
    if (&UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification != NULL) {
//Register for a notifiation when application enter into foreground state
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadVCData:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

Regards,
Amit

Comment: Thanks for that Amit, I wasn't real sure on how to check for that.